# Changing layout element attributes in Custom AlertDialog Class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-view

So I am building a really basic app. I'm using an alert dialog to show the user whether they've won or not. What I have done is that I created this class :

```
public class WinLoseDialog {
  Activity activity;
  AlertDialog dialog;
  TextView text;

  public WinLoseDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
  }

  public void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_lose_layout, null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
  }

  public void dismissDialog() {
        dialog.dismiss();
  }
```

}

**What I wanted to do was to make this class as reusable as possible. I want to be able to use this for an alert dialog in case the user wins as well as in case they lose, for all of my game fragments.**

To do this I need to able to **change the text on the textView** defined as follows (in the win_lose_layout) :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/alertDialogText"
            tools:text="hi" />
```

and the **Raw res for my lottie View** defined as (in the win_lose_layout):

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/lottie"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
```

And I need **to be able to change the above two from inside the fragment** where I am using this WinLoseDialog class.

**The thing I'm stuck on** is how do I use something like findViewById in this so that I'm able to attach the TextView object in my class to that in the win_lose_layout, so that i have the ability to create a setter for the text (TextView) and use that inside my fragment. And similarly for the lottie View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the method to change those 2 views like this.

```
public class WinLoseDialog {
  Activity activity;
  AlertDialog dialog;
  TextView text;
  LottieAnimationView lottieView;

  public WinLoseDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
  }

  public WinLoseDialog startDialog(String textStr, String lottieFilePath) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_lose_layout, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        text = view.findViewById(R.id.alertText);
        lottieView = view.findViewById(R.id.lottie);
        
        //You can update your text & Lottie animation view here with the new string and new Lottie path you got from arguments.

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(textStr))
            text.settext(textStr);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lottieFilePath))
            //Set your animation file path here.

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    return this;
  }

  public void dismissDialog() {
        dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Now, when you want to sue the dialog without the changes, then simply :

```
WinLoseDialog dialog = new WinLoseDialog(activity);
dialog.startDialog(null, null);
dialog.show()
```

With the changes :

```
WinLoseDialog dialog = new WinLoseDialog(activity);
dialog.startDialog("This is new Text", lottiePath);
dialog.show()
```